# Enable and Disable Input Field On Click (not toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Q: How do i make a field disable and then another one enable when clicking on an anchor tag.

Progress so far: Disabling the field works, but Re-enabling the field is just another click away unfortunately. Also, the second field doesn't get enabled on the click.

```js
// When clicking "Lock your username" that input field should be disabled, 
//and the Comment section should be enabled
$("#lock").click(function() {
  $("#sender").attr('disabled', !$("#sender").attr('disabled'));
  $("#message").attr('disabled', !$("#message").attr('enabled'));

});

//problems right now:
// clicking twice re-enables the field.
// from what i've understood, disabled fields cannot be targeted with event handlers?
//
//
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formInput">
  <input type="text" id="sender" placeholder="Your Name" />

  <a id="lock" style="border:1px solid rgba(000,200,000,0.5);background:#ccc;cursor:pointer;padding:2px;width:150px">Lock your username</a>

  <div id="messages" style="height:100px; border:1px solid #000;width:200px;">
    &nbsp; Messages will go here
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="write your comment here" autocomplete="off" disabled />
  <input type="submit" id="send" style="border:1px solid rgba(000,200,000,0.5);background:#ccc;cursor:pointer;padding:2px;width:150px" value="send message" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is remove the handler after the click if you only want it to be done once.  Something like this:

```
var lockHandler = function () {
    $('#sender').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#message').attr('disabled', null);
    $('#lock').off('click', lockHandler);
}

$('#lock').on('click', lockHandler);
```

Probably also want to check to make sure there is an actual user name entered before removing it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clever solution!

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
$("#lock").click(function(){
    $("#sender").attr('disabled', !$("#sender").attr('disabled')); 
    $("#message").attr('disabled', !$("#message").attr('disabled')); 
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4u5yuu6f/

Comment: Thanks for your input but however, if you click multiple times, the disabling just switches.

Answer (score 2):

For Jquery 1.6+ you can use

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function)** with callback function , this will toggle the disabled property

```js
$("#lock").click(function(e) {
  $("#sender,#message").prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
    return !v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formInput">
  <input type="text" id="sender" placeholder="Your Name" />
  <a id="lock" style="border:1px solid rgba(000,200,000,0.5);">Lock your username</a>
  <div id="messages" style="height:100px; border:1px solid #000;width:200px;">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="comment here" autocomplete="off" disabled/>
  <input type="button" id="send" value="send message" />
</form>
```

If you want only execute it once then use **[`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

```js
$("#lock").one('click', function(e) {
  $("#sender,#message").prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
    return !v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formInput">
  <input type="text" id="sender" placeholder="Your Name" />
  <a id="lock" style="border:1px solid rgba(000,200,000,0.5);">Lock your username</a>
  <div id="messages" style="height:100px; border:1px solid #000;width:200px;">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="comment here" autocomplete="off" disabled/>
  <input type="button" id="send" value="send message" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution. However, if you click the "lock your username" multiple times it just switches.